# JQuery toggle between hide and show for the nearest div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to press a div and then the nearest element with the class name appear and disappears.

However, my attempts are not successful.

This is my function:

```
function showHide() {
  $(".sectionTitle").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".news").toggle();
  });
}
```

And I want to click on the `<h2>` tag to make the `div` under it with the class name `news` to disappears.

```
<h2 id="Title1" class="sectionTitle"> Title </h2>
<div id="news" class="news"></div>
```

Right now, nothing happens and I get no error in my console.

```js
function showHide() {
  $(".sectionTitle").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".news").toggle();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="Title1" class="sectionTitle"> Title </h2>
<div id="news" class="news">news</div>
```

Comment: Your code is work. Run  snippet. Either you forgot to call your function or problem is some where else.

Comment: @Shree you just  edited it to correct answer, is it a valid question now?

Comment: Na I just want to say OP  code is fine. Problem is some where else.  There is not any console error .  Non reproducible.

Comment: @Shree but now there is no difference in between the question and the answer, right?

Comment: I am not against your answer. But main concern is  question is not  reproducible. Code work as it is. There is not any console error.  I am voting to close the question

Comment: @Shree I didn't say that you're against my answer :D, did I? I found answering the question in question it self, doesn't serve the purpose of the question, even if the question has some syntax error, closing it with proper reason will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unwrap it from function `showHide()` or invoke this function immediate after declaring, and your code will work.

With removing the function.

```js
$(".sectionTitle").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".news").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="Title1" class="sectionTitle"> Title </h2>
<div id="news" class="news">News</div>
```

---

With invoking the function.

```js
function showHide() {
  $(".sectionTitle").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings(".news").toggle();
  });
};

showHide()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="Title1" class="sectionTitle"> Title </h2>
<div id="news" class="news">News</div>
```